# Limit of the Limit functor

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

let $X$ be small-complete and $J$ small categories, then we can define the functor
$$
  \operatorname{Lim} \colon X^J \to X
$$
which sends each functor
$$
  F \colon J \to X
$$
to its limit.

I have been thinking, when does the $\operatorname{Lim}$ functor have a limit? If $X^J$ is small, by completeness of $X$ there must exist the limit of $\operatorname{Lim}$, and then my question is how to find this limit?

Comment: If $X^J$ is small then $X$ must be small, and if $X$ is small and complete then an argument due to Freyd shows it must be a preorder. (So the limit is the initial object.)

Comment: Something doesn't seem right there. If $X$ has an initial object then $X^J$ also has an initial object. The limit of a diagram whose shape has an initial object is simply the value at the initial object. But the limit of a diagram of initial objects is not necessarily an initial object.